# more efficient version of this?

Tags: algorithm

i have this thingy here :

```
function numOfPackets(bufferSize, packetSize) {
    if (bufferSize <= 0 || packetSize > bufferSize) return 0;
    if (packetSize < 0) throw Error();
    var out = 0;


    for(;;){
     out++; 
     bufferSize = bufferSize - packetSize;
     if( packetSize > bufferSize ) break;
    }

    return out;
}
```

which i run at often , can u give me more efficent variant of it?

Comment: What language are you writing? Please tag appropriately.

Comment: i dont care of language, i encounter it in many projects with different languages and libraries

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I guess that you write in JavaScript or something similar, in which case use:

```
function numOfPackets(bufferSize, packetSize) {
    if (bufferSize <= 0) return 0;
    if (packetSize <= 0) throw Error();
    return Math.floor(bufferSize / packetSize);
}
```

Also note that your original code enters an infinite loop when `packetSize = 0`;

Equivalently in C++:

```
int numOfPackets(int bufferSize, int packetSize) {
    if (bufferSize <= 0) return 0;
    if (packetSize <= 0) throw Error();
    return bufferSize / packetSize;
}
```

Comment: beware of integer division: int/int returns an int not a float

Comment: no this is not it, if i have numOfPackets(901,900) it returns 2 but it supposed to return 1; in other words it lokks of how many qwhole packets fits in buffer of certain size. and this solution uses library which i may not have

Comment: Your return value is off by one, as the original loop tests against packetSize rather than zero.

Comment: @john use Math.floor instead of Math.ceil to get what you want.

Comment: @john: Fixed. also you don't need any library, any modern language has support for mathematical floor function.